# Ionic 3 how to implement application user settings and store them

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, mobile, ionic3

I tried looking for a tutorial on this, but I didn't really find one that was helpful.

I have an Ionic 3 application, and I want to have some user settings for various little small things, that should be accessible from any part of the application (and any part of the code). These settings would also have to be stored on the device, so they should be saved somewhere.

How can I achieve this with Ionic 3?
Do I need to have a "provider" for this, and import that provider into all of my pages, and have a 'getSetting' and 'setSetting' that's accessible through this provider?

Or is there a special way to actually handle this?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Ionic Storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/). This will make it possible to save variables or something like json to the local storage of the device.

You don't have to use some other provider, as you can just import the Ionic Storage one.